# Django 1.5 - 'module' object has no attribute 'simple_class_factory'

Tags: django, upgrade, compatibility

I've set up a new server with Django 1.5.4 to test one of my applications and have encountered a problem (the app is working fine in Django 1.4.2)

```
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'simple_class_factory'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/se‌​ssions/serializers.py in loads, line 17 Python
Executable: /usr/bin/python Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Any suggestions?

This may be related but I'm stumped: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20289

Comment: You should show us some of your relevant code. `simple_class_factory` is a internal Django function removed in version 1.5. It was never intended to be used in outside code. You may be importing it or trying to load some objects that were serialized in Django 1.4.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll happily show you relevant code, but I have not called simple_class_factory, so not even sure what is relevant here. Does this help?

Django Version:  1.5.4
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'module' object has no attribute 'simple_class_factory'

Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sessions/serializers.py in loads, line 17
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:  2.7.3

Comment: Thank you. I edited your question to include the whole trace and also posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some user session objects created in Django 1.4, that are not compatible with your newer Django installation. You need to clear user sessions:

```
python manage.py clearsessions
```

---

This will clear all the session data from the server. Unfortunately if your `SESSION_ENGINE` is set to `signed_cookies` the session data is kept in users' browsers and not the server, so clearing it on the server won't do much.

You can invalidate all the old cookies on users' computers, by changing the `SECRET_KEY` setting (there is [a generator you can use to get another random value](http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/)).

Alternatively, if the site is not in production and you are the only user, just clear cookies in your own browser and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Ludwik - tried that (and removed all .pyc files too) but no joy. Also tried with a clean database and ran python manage.py syncdb - same result.

Comment: **UPDATE** - seems like this is specific to the application I first tried - I just tried another application and that worked fine without any trouble.

I will post an update here when I figure out what's going on...

Comment: the problem app is using a custom shopping basket that used sessions. I disabled this line **SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"** in settings.py and the app runs (not sure what this breaks, but I am making some progress) - thanks for your assistance:

Comment: In that case... the problem may be with session cookies in YOUR browser. `clearsessions` command obviously can't reach those. Have you tried enabling this line and clearing your cookies?

Comment: **SOLVED BUT NOT QUITE EXPLAINED** - seems like commenting out the session_engine may have cleared something that clearsessions didn't. Now when I uncomment it & restart, everything is working. Didn't do anything to my local cookies - but I didn't think the error indicated something local in nature. Many thanks again for your help here.

Comment: In the meantime I updated my answer. The explanation may be the cookie on your computer have just expired on its own.

Comment: Lessons learned:  
- ask Ludwik ;)
- don't assume it's not a local cookie problem
- as usual, persistence pays off

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same issue in Django 1.10. The new version does not know how to unpickle the old version cache.

So it's **not related to the sessions**, but to the cache.

You need to either (A) clear the cache, or (B) version up the cache.

### (A) Clear the cache

Run this manually in a shell.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

Note that you could have downtime, so it's better to just increase the version...

### (B) Version up (recommended)

Set/increase the `VERSION` inside your `CACHE` setting (see [cache versioning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-versioning)). Example:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        (...)
        'VERSION': 2,
    }
}
```